# Is surjective holomorphic self-map on compact complex manifold finite?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $X$ be a compact connected complex manifold.

Let $f:X \to X$ be a **surjective** holomorphic map then can we say that $f$ is a finite map (i.e., every point has finitely many preimages)?

If $X$ is one dimensional then the answer to the above question is yes. If $X$ is a complex projective space then also answer is yes.

If we don’t assume surjectivity then we can easily construct non constant non finite map (just consider product manifold and $f$ to be projection on one of the coordinates).

I am unable to produce counterexample in the general case. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Visit https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377353/is-surjective-holomorphic-self-map-on-compact-complex-manifold-finite for the answer.